# npm install WARNs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've tried updating npm after I did some WARNings, so I went

```
npm audit fix
```

received way more WARNs. Now when i tried installing all dependencies with

```
npm i
```

I got tons of WARN (see below). I honestly haven't got a clue what any of these mean, but did not have any before the npm fix.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using deprecated packages.
Try running

```bash
npm outdated
```

it will show you the current version, desired version, and latest version for each of your package. That won't actually do anything to your project, but it's a good first indication.

If you run

```bash
npm update
```

it will update each package according to what your package.json says.
For instance if you see this in your package.json

```
"my-package": "~1.25.0"
```

it means that `npm update` will update to (or that `npm install` will install) version 1.25.0 or the latest patch version such as 1.25.4.

If you see

```
"my-package": "^1.25.0"
```

it means that `npm update` will update to (or that `npm install` will install) version 1.25.0 or the latest minor or patch version such as 1.26.2.

However, `npm update` will not update your packages to new major versions. That means that "my-package" will not be update to 2.0.0 for instance.

I think using old version of packages can cause those kinds of warnings.
In that case, just reinstall the package to the latest version

```
npm uninstall my-package
npm i my-package
```

⚠️ But **be careful** as updating a package to a new major version could break your code!

My advice is to do it step by step and make sure you can always roll back in case there's a problem you don't understand!

Comment: This is so helpful that I can't even express it with words. Thank you so so much! Unfortunately haven't got 15 rep to upvote it tho.